# Node.js application nodemailer/mailgun transport not working when hosted

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a node.js application hosted with A2 hosting. I'm using `nodemailer` and `mailgun` on the server to process emails from the website. The code works perfectly locally but not when hosted. Any ideas of what might be causing the problem or on how to trouble shoot?

I am a new developer and I am not sure how to access the console when the application is hosted to verify that the email is sending like I do on gitBash when I'm running the application locally.

Here's the mail.js file:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailGun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
require('dotenv').config();

const key = process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY;

const auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: `${key}`,
        domain: 'MY DOMAIN'

    }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));

const sendMail = (email, firstName, lastName, phone, helpType, message, cb) => {
    const pcsEmail = {
        from: email,
        to: 'MY EMAIL',
        subject: 'A new message from your website',
        text: "Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + "Phone Number: " + phone + "\n" + "Type of Help: " + helpType + "\n" + "Message: " + message
    };

    const confirmEmail = {
        from: 'MY EMAIL',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Email confirmation',
        text: "Hello there " + firstName + "," + "\n" + "\n" + "Thank you for contacting Pisgah Climbing School. The following email was sent to Pisgah Climbing School:" + "\n" + "\n" + message + "\n" + "\n" + "A PCS representative will contact you soon!"
        };

        Promise.all([
            transporter.sendMail(pcsEmail),
            transporter.sendMail(confirmEmail),
        ])
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));

}; 

exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

UPDATE: Problem solved. A2 hosting added logs for my server (which apparently I needed to request...). From the logs and the help of the A2 support people, we noted that I had been using replaceAll() in my javascript which is supported in the most recent node.js server but not the version that the hosting supports. Using replaceAll() threw an error which impeded the processing of anything from the server. This explains why mail was going through on my localhost and not the server...my localhost was using the most up-to-date version of node.js.

Comment: did you set the `env` variable in the hosted environment? you can access the logs in an hosting platform, check under setting

Comment: I set the env variable, yes but wondering if the problem is that the env variable cannot be accessed somehow from the mail.js file. It is at the same level as the index.js server code. Maybe I should just put the key in the code rather than using the env variable?

Comment: No in any hosting server have an option to add env/sceret keys. check A2 Hosting

Comment: Right, the environment variables are all set up. One thing I did do yesterday was change the app from developer mode to production mode and I wonder if that could have done anything.